# UILongPressGestureRecognizer on a navigationbar's view

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using this code to show a round user's avatar on my navigation bar:

```
UIView *avatView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 190.0f)];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-20, 75, 40, 40)];
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:myUtente.imgData];
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[avatView addSubview:imageView];
self.navBar.titleView = avatView;
```

Now I'd like this avatar to act like a button, with a 2 seconds long press on it, so I've added this code:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(switchUser:)];
[longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:2.0f];
// same code as above
[avatView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
```

The corresponding action never gets called and I don't know why. Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: is all this in one method?

Comment: Add the gesture recognizer to the UIImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the frame of `avatView` and `imageView` then gesture works like a charm.

ex:

```
UIView *avatView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 2, 40, 40)];
```

Comment: Wow, I should have known... Thank you very much, it works perfectly!